# Is there any online service/API to get the complete transaction in raw form?

Tags: api, raw-transaction, mempool.space

Is there any *online service or API* that allows you to get the transaction in raw form, i.e. in "byte" format? I know it can be done through bitcoin core, however, I need some *online service/API*. Also, I know that the [mempool.space](https://mempool.space/) site shows certain parts of the transaction in raw format, however, I need a view of the entire transaction in raw form.

Is there such an online service/API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of several public APIs that can return serialized transactions:

- mempool.space: https://mempool.space/api/tx/$txid/hex
- blockstream.info: https://blockstream.info/api/tx/$txid/hex
- blockchain.info: https://blockchain.info/rawtx/$txid?format=hex
- blockchair.com: https://api.blockchair.com/bitcoin/raw/transaction/$txid (returns a JSON where one of the fields is the serialized transaction)